# How do I return true/false based on if I get stderr or stdout?

Tags: linux, bash, boolean, stdout, stderr

I am making a bash script that will remove hacking tools/unnecessary packages on a Linux machine. I want to have it take in a blacklist of packages and loop through checking if they are installed with `dpkg -s [INSERT PACKAGE NAME HERE]` and return true if the command returns stdout and return false if the command returns stderr, and then send everything that had it set to true go into an array that we can loop through to remove. I can do this by sending every packages output to a file and then searching it for the error message, but I just want to have a method that is a bit more elegant. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're examining them at all, instead of just going by exit status as in  `if dpkg -s "yourpackage" > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "It's installed"; fi`

Comment: @thatotherguy I don’t quite follow what your saying, would you be willing to explain how this works? I’m rather new to bash.

Comment: All commands return an exit code indicating whether they failed or succeeded, and this is easy to check in a script. Generally, only humans look at stderr while scripts ignore it and use the exit code.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks!